# Как вывести все варианты перестановки пар цифр числа long?

Tags: java, перебор

Имеется некое число long
Как можно было бы вывести все варианты перестановки пар цифр этого числа?

например для числа 134 вывести
134
431
314
143

то есть переставлять можно только 2 числа

Comment: Вывести, например в консоль, можно в файл, можно сохранить в базу данных ( если это считается выводом). Больше вариантов нет.

Comment: Ну так и свапай каждую возможную пару. Два вложенных цикла, как при сортировке пузырём, проще некуда... и вали всё в массив. Потом убирай дубликаты, и выводи... согласно предыдущему комментарию.

Comment: `переставлять можно только 2 числа` (наверное - цифры) как-то не согласуется с приведённым примером

Comment: @MBo Где ж это видано, чтобы студент до конца задачу решал, да ещё вручную...

Comment: Посчитай максимальное количество знаков в этом числе и возведи в 10 степень

Answer (score 2):

Если переставлять можно только два числа.

```java
char[] number = Long.toString(134).toCharArray();
System.out.println(number);

for(int i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
    for(int j = i + 1; j < number.length; j++) {
        if (number[i] != number[j]) {
            char ni = number[i];
            char nj = number[j];

            number[i] = nj;
            number[j] = ni;

            System.out.println(number);

            number[i] = ni;
            number[j] = nj;
        }
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
134
314
431
143
```

Comment: @ИмяФамилия я прямо даже не знаю, стоило ли мне правку принимать или просить вас отдельным ответом ответить :)